# C# print every third number!

Tags: c#

Help needed to perform an output in C# console application.

I have a maximum number

```
int maxNr = 10;
int myValue = 1;

public void myMethod(){
int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  // only 1 or 2 accepted.

//Only choice = 1 in displayed here.
if(choice == 1){
   while(myValue <= maxNr){
     Console.WriteLine(myValue);
     myValue = myValue + 3;
   }
}
}
```

Expected output:
1, 4, 7, 10
Next time the function is called the output should be:
3, 6, 9
2, 5, 8

Comment: Do you mean the next output should be: 3,6,9,12,15,18? Also, this sounds like a homework problem. If it is, you should tag it as homework...

Comment: what exactly do u mean by "next time the function is called"? Do you want the user to enter a number each time or only once?

Comment: what is your exact problem? The code is okay, but the part with "next time the function is called", beginning with 3, and the next time with 2. you sure about the order?

Comment: My only problem is when it exceeds 10. For example myValue is 9 and if I add 3 to that then it exceeds 10 which it is not allowed to do. Instead the method call should start at 2 (three steps from 9, 1, 2).

Comment: I don't get it. You expect the same output on every call? or just max `myValue` at 10 (10 + 1 = 1)? **EDIT**: You answer it already in the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

myValue is stuck at 13 after the first call, so the code does not enter the loop the second time

Answer (score 2):

Add this before the while loop:

```
if (myValue >= 10)
    myValue -= 10;
```

**Edit:**

1.If I understood you correctly, the expected output is:

```
1st call 1, 4, 7, 10.
2nd call: 3, 6, 9.
3rd call 2, 5, 8.
```

2.As some suggested, you should use `for` loop instead of `while` loops:

```
if (myValue >= maxNr)
    myValue -= maxNr;

for (; myValue <= maxNr; myValue += 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myValue);
}
```

Comment: should be `myValue > 10` though, then 10 is still shown as (s)he wants it. And it should not be before the while loop, but after incrementing myValue.

Comment: @Sören: My answer was on 4th revision (2nd call: 3, 6, 9. 3rd call 2, 5, 8). If I understand current revision correctly (2nd call: 3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8) then you are correct.

Comment: @Sören: you are correct. To do so one should use [`do while` loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx "do (C# Reference)")

Answer (score 1):

`for (i=0; i<n; i+=3)` don't work for you?

Comment: *Next time the function is called* - there was another requirement!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this?

```
for (int i = n; i <= maxNr; i = i+3) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

myValue is not defined locally, so you need to set it to 0, when calling the method again, otherwise it would still be 10 and you do not enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void myMethod(){
int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  // only 1 or 2 accepted.

int maxNr = 10;
int myValue = choice;

//Only choice = 1 in displayed here.
if(choice == 1){
   while(myValue <= maxNr){
     Console.WriteLine(myValue);
     myValue = myValue + 3;
   }
}
}
```

Reset your starting value each time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `myValue` in a temporary variable and update it before exiting the method. As I understand your requirements the code to achieve the output is as given below,

```
static int maxNr = 10;
static int myValue = 1;

private static void Test()
{
    int lastValue = myValue;
    int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  // only 1 or 2 accepted.

    //Only choice = 1 in displayed here.
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        while (myValue <= maxNr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myValue);
            myValue = myValue + 3;
        }
    }

    if (lastValue == 1)
    {
        myValue = lastValue + 3 - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        myValue = lastValue - 1;
    }
}
```

**Method Call**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test();
    Test();
    Test();
```

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

}


**Output** 

`1`

`4`

`7`

`10`


`3` 

`6`

`9`


`2`

`5`

`8`

Note that the user needs to enter the value `1` at every function call.